# Comparing two Cells in two different Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the following error message when comparing two cells in two different worksheets:

Run-Time Error '1004'
Application-defined or Object-defined Error

```
For j = 2 To 10
            For k = 1 To 26
               If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, k).Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(j, k).Text Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, k).Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(j, k).Text
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(j, k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
               End If
            Next k
Next j
```

Comment: Is it possible you put the code in a worksheet module instead of in a general module?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Value` or `Value2`. See MSDN for differences:

```
The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types.
```

[MSDN Value2 vs Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215938%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
For j = 2 To 10
            For k = 1 To 26
               If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k).Value Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k).Value
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
               End If
            Next k
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

This will correct your issue:

```
Sub test_me()
  For j = 2 To 10
    For k = 1 To 26
       If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
       End If
    Next k
  Next j
End Sub
```

If you do not force Excel to a specific data type, that will allow the comparison to occur.  Depending on exactly what you are trying to compare, you could be running into typing discrepancies.  While I tend to avoid the use of the `Not` operator, that is generally a preference so I left your use of it in the above code.  Also, depending on how you are calling this code, that could be the cause of your error.  I placed this in its own sub in a separate module, and ran it without issue.